# Conditional probability for bivariate random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

question: $$ f_{(X,Y)(x,y)}=
\begin{cases} 8xy, &0\le y\le x \le 1\\0.&\text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Find $ P\left( X\le \frac{1}{2}|Y\ge \frac{1}{4}\right) $

What is wrong with my solution:

$$
\frac{\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x8xydydx}{\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1}4y-4y^3dy}
$$

seeing that $ 4y-4y^3 $is the marginal pdf of Y

Comment: The lower bound of the inner integral of the numerator should not be $0$, since the numerator is $P(X\leq \frac12 \cap Y\geq \frac14)$. Also, the denominator lacks a $\mathrm dy$.

Comment: then it should be right?

Comment: It looks good to me now. Now compute the integrals.

Comment: yes I have and it is the same as the solution, however the solution has this form, can you tell me why it is also correct? $
\frac{\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x8xydydx}{\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1}\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x8xydydx}
$

Comment: In this form, the numerator is the same, and the denominator is the expression $P(Y\geq\frac14)$ when you don't use the marginal but the bivariate density.

Comment: Yes I am having trouble understanding that part. Is there an intuitive explanation why the denominator gives that probability. Thanks

Comment: The marginal is $f_Y(y)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm dx$. Your denominator is thus a double integral in disguise, when the order of integration is $\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$. In the comment, you give an integral with order $\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$. Be careful with the bounds when switching the order of intergation. To make things clear, always draw the domain.

Comment: can you tell me why the lower bound is 0 and not y?

Comment: In the marginal? It doesn't matter, as $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ when $x<y$. You could as well integrate over $\Bbb R$. However, if you want to write the integral of $8xy$, you have to take care of the bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We note that the probability density function is:
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 8xy & 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases} $$

We can visualize the three regions of interest for this problem,

- $\color{darkblue}{\text{The support of the distribution, the set }  S  \text{ of points } (x,y) \text{ such that } 0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1}$
- $\color{goldenrod}{\text{The set }  R_1  \text{ of points } (x,y) \text{ such that } x \leq \frac{1}{2}}$
- $\color{green}{\text{The set }  R_2  \text{ of points } (x,y) \text{ such that } y \geq \frac{1}{4}}$

as follows:

[image: The conditional probability can be ex]

The conditional probability can be expressed as:
$$ \mathbb{P} \left[X \leq \frac{1}{2} \,\,\bigg\rvert\,\, Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right] = \frac{\mathbb{P} \left[X \leq \frac{1}{2} , Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right]}{\mathbb{P} \left[Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right]} $$
The numerator probability is calculated by integrating the probability density function over the area where the event is true, which is $R_1 \cap R_2$ (and, since we don't care about zero probability mass, this region's intersection with the support $S$). We use the colored diagram to see what this region is and what the limits of integration are. We see that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \left[X \leq \frac{1}{2} , Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right] &= \iint_{R_1 \cap R_2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dA \\
&= \iint_{R_1 \cap R_2 \cap S} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dA \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2} \int_\frac{1}{4}^x 8xy \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2} \left[ 4xy^2 \right]_{y = \frac{1}{4}}^{y=x} \, dx \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2} \left(4x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x \right) \, dx \\
&= \left[x^4 - \frac{x^2}{8} \right]_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{32} -\frac{1}{256} + \frac{1}{16\cdot8} \\
&= \frac{16-8-1+2}{256} \\
&= \frac{9}{256} \\
\end{align*}

The denominator probability is calculated similarly on $R_2$ (and its intersection with the support $S$, since its where the probability mass is). We use the colored diagram to see what this region is and what the limits of integration are. We see that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P} \left[Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right] &= \iint_{R_2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dA \\
&= \iint_{R_2 \cap S} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dA \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{4}^1 \int_\frac{1}{4}^x 8xy \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_\frac{1}{4}^1 \left(4x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x \right) \, dx \\
&= \left[x^4 - \frac{x^2}{8} \right]_\frac{1}{4}^1 \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{256} + \frac{2}{256} \\
&= \frac{7}{8} + \frac{1}{256} \\
&= \frac{225}{256}
\end{align*}

Putting the results together, we see that the conditional probability we are looking for is:
$$ \mathbb{P} \left[X \leq \frac{1}{2} \,\,\bigg\rvert\,\, Y \geq \frac{1}{4} \right] = \frac{9}{225} $$

Answer (score 1):

Regards @matt . If I may contribute. Isn't 
$$  P \left( \small{ X \le \frac{1}{2} | Y \ge \frac{1}{4} } \right) =  \frac{P(X \le \frac{1}{2} \cap Y \ge \frac{1}{4} )}{ P (Y \ge \frac{1}{4})}  \:\:\:\: ?$$

The numerator should be : $$ \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{x} \: (8xy) \: dy \: dx $$

to avoid confusion, you could draw the $x$-$y$ diagram to make a clear view of the area. The area for the numerator is the area below the line $y(x) = x$, with $ \frac{1}{4} \le x \le \frac{1}{2} $, its a triangle.

Regards, Arief.

Comment: Politeness is appreciated on StackExchange, however there is no need to add greetings to posts. The idea is to make posts contain as much useful information as possible in the shortest length. Information such as "Regards, Arief" is unlikely to be useful to a unregistered user who is using your post.